# How to use Expressions in QML file in QGIS 3.x

Tags: pyqgis-3, expression, qml

I have a plugin that uses optional QML files for layer labels.  If I use a standard field name for the value, it works fine, but if I use an expression, it will not display the label UNLESS I open and close the Properties dialog for the layer.

This works:
`<property key="labeling/fieldName" value="id"/>`

This does not:
`<property key="labeling/fieldName" value="concat(id, ' - ', acquisition)"/>`

The code is fairly simple:

```
        style_path = os.path.normpath(QgsApplication.qgisSettingsDirPath() +
                                      f'/python/plugins/S2SRoadNet/{fnm}')
        self.dbshp.segments_layer.loadNamedStyle(style_path)
        self.iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(self.dbshp.segments_layer.id())
```

What is the Properties dialog doing that `refreshLayerSymbology` is not and how can I run whatever that process is in code to get the expression to work in the QML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an "isExpression" value that must be set to True if the value is not a simple field value.

`<property key="labeling/isExpression" value="True"/>`

This properly formats the label.